# Changing the login name for user dbo

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, security, logins, domain

I have a database where the owner is Login1 but the username dbo is assigned to Login - login2. I understand in order to change the login name for the username dbo to sa I will have to use the below 
EXEC ***sp_changedbowner 'sa'*** but the problem here is that this will change the databasowner from Login1 to sa. How do I only change the dbo login name to sa and keep the database owner to Login1

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge you can't change the **dbo** user without changing the entry in **sys.databases**.  This is a case where the same piece of data (the owner of the database) is set it in two places.  While they do occasionally become out of sync they mean the same thing.

If you need someone to have database owner access then just add them to the *db_owner* role. Really the main difference between *dbo* and members of *db_owner* is that members of *db_owner* can be denied permissions while the actual *dbo* can't.